# Regular Expression for a string with 5 or no digits

Tags: java, regex, string

Am trying to write a regex that captures a string followed by exactly 5 or no digits

Regex should match `Passport` `Passport11111` `Passport12345` but shouldn't match `Passport1` `Passport123` `Passport123456`

I tried using Passport\d{5*} but its not working. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
Passport(\d{5})?
```

The parentheses *capture* their contents (i.e. they create a group), but they also provide a way to make a part of the pattern atomic, so you can - for example - make it optional with `?`.

BTW, you can write parentheses that don't capture but make atomic only by adding an option to them:

```
Passport(?:\d{5})?
```

Comment: Not sure if capturing groups will change anything if only `test` is used. I guess the group is still created since you could write a backreference. However, in practice I would considering adding ?: a premature optimization.

Comment: Non-capturing groups do not change the *behavior* of the expression. They change the *group count* of the expression. Some regex engines only have 9 groups and in complex situations you can run out. Or you simply want to conserve resources by not capturing stuff you are not interested in. And no, you cannot use a back-reference to a non-capturing group. That would defy the purpose, wouldn't it? (BTW, I added the second paragraph as a "BTW", not as a "you should do this")